# What case is virtutis in "prope virum summae virtutis sto"?

Tags: syntax, translation-check, genitive, case

Consider the sentence, "prope virum summae virtutis sto." What case is *virtutis* and why?

I'm pretty sure that it is genitive due to description, but I'm not sure. In case it helps, I translated it as, "I stood near the man with the most courage."

Comment: I have no answer. I am attempting to put into English the definition on my family crest, " Virtutis Amore ". I have found everything very interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed genitive.
First, no other form of *virtus* looks like *virtutis*.
For that reason alone, it has to be genitive.

But what is the genitive doing in the sentence?
The *virtus* comes with the adjective *summa*.
[*Virtus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=virtus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) can have many meanings, and "courage" is indeed a possible translation.
Together *summa virtus* means "highest courage".
Therefore *vir summae virtutis* means "a man of the highest courage".

While this translation is possible in English, it often most natural to translate with an adjective: "a very courageous man".
Your translation "with the most courage" is possible as well.
It should be noted that the superlative here is probably absolute; it does not express comparison ("most courageous of all") but just extent ("very courageous").

This Latin construction of using the genitive to express quality is known as *genetivus qualitatis* (the qualitative genitive).
The ablative can be used similarly.

Finally, let me remark that *sto* is present tense.
I would translate the sentence to English as "I stand near a very courageous man".
However, this is not **the** correct translation — there are several ways to go about this translation task.

Comment: @Zanolon I'm glad to be able to help! I hope you'll stick around and ask more questions (and take a look at our [tour] if you haven't yet).

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm really not great at latin so I assume I'll be making frequent stops by. ^_^